# random bipartite network generator in JUNG

Tags: java, graph, generator, jung

I am trying to implement the simple random bipartite generator described in Guillam, Latapy, "Bipartite graphs as models of complex networks", Physica A 371 (2006) 795–813.

The rules are quite simple:
- create top nodes and bottom nodes
- assign to each node a degree (the distribution for top and bottom nodes must be consistent with each other - in my case, I have empirical data to feed top and bottom nodes)
- randomly connect nodes from top and bottom sets

The code I have so far is:

```
UndirectedSparseGraph<Node, Edge> random = new UndirectedSparseGraph<Node, Edge>();
// totalLinks is the number of edges in the empirical network
while (totalLinks > 0) {
 Node u = topNodes.get(cntxt.getRNG().nextInt(topNodes.size()));
 Node t = bottomNodes.get(cntxt.getRNG().nextInt(bottomNodes.size()));
 // if both nodes can accept new links, i.e. the actual degree is lower than 
 // the assigned degree
 if(u.getFinalDegree()>random.degree(u) && t.getFinalDegree()>random.degree(t)){
   // create the new link
   random.addEdge(new Edge(0), u, t, EdgeType.UNDIRECTED);
   // decrement total links
   totalLinks--;
 }
}
```

This approach is simple but produces multiple edges. The result is that the final degree distribution is different from the empirical one.

Could someone suggest a way to overcome this issue? I am thinking about weighting the links, and then set the degree of a node as the sum of the weights of its links... Or maybe JUNG can handle multiple links?

Best regards,
Simone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JUNG can handle multiple edges with the right implementation; look for classes that have "Multi" in the name.

Or you can look to see if two nodes already are connected and pick another pair if they are.

Comment: that won't work Joshua :) if you avoid connect nodes that are already neighbors, you will end up for sure with at least a top node that does not have a free bottom node to link with. I'll have a look at the Multi* stuff. Thanks.

Comment: Why would you always end up with an imbalance unless your degree requirements are overconstrained?  Can you give a simple example?

Comment: Yes, of course, the problem is not the graph structure, but the sequence used in linking nodes. Take this graph, letters for top nodes and number for bottom nodes:
'At-1b
Bt-1b
Ct-1b
Dt-2b
Et-1b
Et-2b'
Now try to rewire it. If by chance At and Bt rewire to 2b, then Et has two links to do, but only 1b is available, thus either you allow multiple edges, or you lose an edge. Or you bias the process by allowing nodes with higher degree to go first, but I am unsure how this affect the randomness of the generator.

Comment: OK, so that was an exaggeration, got it.  :)  Yes, if you're trying to make the degree distribution exactly the same, then you may sometimes have to remove edges and try again; multiple edges won't solve that problem.  However, if you're just trying to get the distribution to be similar, you can assign probabilities to each node as a function of (a) its degree in the target distribution, or (b) both the current assignments and the target (e.g., if this node already has enough neighbors, drop its probability; you can be more clever/general but you get the idea).